# Evernote search grammar: how to search based on names of attachments

Tags: evernote

I want to get all the notes that have a non "common" type with specific name.

For instance I want all the notes that have attached a file named "my.cnf"

Comment: I consider myself very good with EN and I have no idea what you are asking...

Comment: Basically say you have a file that has an uncommon name and you have placed this file attached as a note. Now you want to be able to find such note based on the name of that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for

> filename:my.cnf

... to search for all notes with an file called "my.cnf" attached.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know if I missed this but I have never seen that element published. This is the answer.